Render html content in rich text - Contentful + Next.js
I am building a website using Next.js and Contentful. Now I want to render html content something like <span style="font-size: 18px">View</span> in Contentful rich text. I am not sure if this is possible even.
Can you give me the solution to do this? Thank you in advance.

I did a similar solution using the @contentful/rich-text-react-renderer package.
I tried to render content like the following HTML to render buttons and tips on my website.
<div>
  <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-weight: 700;">This is your journey guide!</div>
</div>

You can check more details here

Oh, thank you for quick reply! May you help me how to render CodeBlock in details?

In my Contentful, CodeBlock has a 'code' field and it renders like the following:
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content.fields.code! }} />

For better understanding, you can reference the following options in documentToReactComponents. renderEmbeddedEntry is to render CodeBlock.
const options = {   renderNode: {     [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY]: (node: Node) => (       <div>         { renderEmbeddedEntry(node.data.target) }       </div>     ),   }, };
